# How to set and transpose columns for time series plotting in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, self

[image: This is unemployment for women data in the US]
How do you process this data into:

- the first column to be 'date' that has 'Jan-00, Feb-00, Mar-00...'
- the second column into 'value' that has '2730, 2718, 2847...'
- so on so forth

for time series plotting?

Thank you! Please let me know if my question is not clear!

Comment: `.melt(id_vars=["Year"], var_name="Month")` I leave combining the year and month to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=["Year"], var_name="Month")
df['Year-Month'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.strptime(str(row['Year'])+'/'+row['Month'], '%Y/%b'), axis=1)
```

And to plot:

```
plt.scatter(df['Year-Month'], df['value'])
```